Better performance for long-term computational simulations: RTX 3080Ti 16GB vs RTX A2000 8GB
I need to know which of these two graphics cards can provide me with better performance for complex computational calculations, specifically simulations of large and complex molecular systems. But also taking into account that these simulations require keeping the computer on all day (24 hours) and up to 2 weeks at a time. I want to ensure that the performance of the calculations does not decrease when these calculations are actively and continuously performed. I also want to clarify that the simulations are performed under CUDA architecture, so which one could obtain better performance in terms of having the simulation results in the shortest time possible?
Thanks

Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! There's a lot of range in terms of GPU compute, and different cards will be suited for different kinds of CUDA. Are the simulations you're doing open source/do you have sample benchmarks available? What bit depth do you run at?

this is complicated however going to depend.
rtx 3080 ti is would do it faster as it has more cores and vram.
Problems rtx 3080ti run hot and powerful so you need to deal with that
rtx a2000 would slower there is slight change in speed depending on software
so rtx 3080 ti would do it if you keep the heat down
notable suggestion try to get a used rtx a4000 from ebay it will do it much better with less of a bill

I don't think this is relevant or even necessarily accurate. It seems like the OP is more concerned as to which will be more performant, not power consumption. In any case, though the 3080 Ti is a more power hungry card, the A2000 may run hotter due to its smaller cooler.
